# How can I restart a Java application when VM (virtual machine) is restart/start?

Tags: java, linux, spring-boot, virtual-machine

I am using java 1.8 and spring-boot-starter-parent 1.5.6.RELEASE and swagger2 2.6.1. We run the application in the VM using the following command,

```
nohup java -jar myApplication.jar &
```

My application is getting stopped when the VM is stopped. So manually I need to start my application. I don't  want to do that manually. I need to restart my application programmatically  or any script will do this that is also fine for me.

How do I restart my application when VM is started??

Kindly provide your inputs.

Comment: Look for OS options. Linux cron job probably.

Comment: start it as a service

Comment: How to start as a service? can you explain in detail.. Thanks!

Comment: simple, open a web browser, type in *create linux service* and then follow the instrcutions

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-linux-service-to-start-automatically-after-a-crash-or-reboot-part-1-practical-examples

Comment: You're asking this back to front. You can't restart this JVM *without* restarting your application. There's only one restart required here, not two.

Comment: Thanks @Scary. Your hint linux service is very useful for me. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

In a Linux distribution which uses [systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) (official docs [here](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/)) (such as [Debian](https://wiki.debian.org/systemd), Ubuntu, or [Fedora](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd)), creating a [service](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html) is simple:

We'll need to create a *service* file which tells systemd how to start your application. Create a file in `/etc/systemd/system` named something like `myApplication.service` containing these lines:

```
[Unit]
Description="A description of what my application does"

[Service]
ExecStart=/path/to/java -jar /path/to/your/myApplication.jar

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

(Derived from [an example in the docs](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#id-1.9.2).)

Then run `systemctl enable myApplication.service` as root to enable it, which will make it run on boot.

There's lots more you can learn; the docs for systemd are quite good. You might take a look at the [blog story](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/systemd.html) which introduced systemd as well, as that provides something of a "sales pitch" for what it can do.